# Macromedia Director: Decompile EXECUTABLE File

Tags: adobe-director

It is possible to extract executable files??

If it is what are the possible software may i use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it depends how deep you want to dig into the executable and what kind of data you need from the exe.
As with all exe files you can analyse them on a low level. But I assume you want to have a high-level tool to get back the director files that were used to create the exe, right?
For the exe-file (the "projector" to use the appropriate director wording) there is no such tool known to me.

But very often the exe file is used together with files with extensions such as .dxr or .dir. Those are director files. DXR-Files are protected. But by importing them into director you can extract some of the cast memebers (graphics etc.) that are included. You need in-deep knowledge of lingo to do so.

You might also find .cst or .cxt files. Those are cast files. They can hold media, scripts etc. too. CXT are the protected versions. For these files the same is true as for the DXR and DIR files.

All in all - it is not easy and your chances are low to completly reveal all code and media. Most director programmer use the protected files for distributing their programs. Those do not allow to reveal all data included.

Answer (score 0):

> This Python script extracts Macromedia / Adobe Director movies and casts
> from Windows and Mac executables.

https://github.com/n0samu/director-files-extract

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).