# How to Decompile an executable file made by old Macromedia Director 7?

Tags: windows, adobe, extract, macromedia, adobe-director

**The original question**:

Now I am trying to extract the resources from this exe file made by old Macromedia Director 7, but I am in trouble.

First, I have tried the way of loading temp files, but they are inside Xtras folder and I also cannot find a way to open those .x32 files. And these .x32 files seem cannot be opened by the Director nowdays or other programs like Authorwave that I have downloaded. I have also tried MX2004, but it fails again. Are the media information coded inside these .x32 files?

Second, I tried using app like Reshacker or Muitextractor but neither of them can load the pictures inside.

I found one Adobe's technical document but not sure if it is useful to my question [link](https://www.adobe.com/support/authorware/basics/files_distribute/files_distribute_02.html). According to it, Win 95, NT and Win3.1 was the environment at that time. I am sure this exe was made by **Macromedia Director 7 in Year 1999**, as the file inforamtion tells me.Here is the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzCxL.png) of the file info.And it is shown as Director Player when I right click it on the task bar.

So, any tips on how to extract the resources I want???

If it is possbile, what are the softwares I need ?  Really want to get the pictures inside.

Comment: Hi @fc2otica. Stackoverflow.com is surely not the place to be asking this type of question. This website is for engineers and programmers who write code and develop software. You will have better luck if you join some forums on the internet that deal with decompiling windows executables and extracting PE data. On a personal note, many years ago, I used to decompile stuff on Windows, I used a program called "PE Explorer", so you might give that a try. Feel free to delete this question, likely it will be closed as off topic.

Comment: Hi @darksky Thanks for your reply. I ask this question at stackflow because I saw there are other similar ones such as this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15824345/macromedia-director-decompile-executable-file here. And what I want to know is just how to decompile or extract executable Macromedia Director files. So personally, I don't think I am off-topic. Maybe is the problem of the way I am asking?

Comment: @darksky For the PE Explorer you mentioned, I believe it is the same funtion as Reshacker. The problem is that these apps can only scan and detect the UI icons for of the handles. so it does not help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're still looking to get the images from the Director .exe,(a Projector I presume?), you might be able to use a converter such as http://swftools.sourceforge.net/exe-to-swf.html which may end up porting the media to a folder. I suggest going down that route. Also try the unofficial Director communities if they are still active http://www.deansdirectortutorials.com/

Hope that helps.